# PHP Refresh Error

Tags: php, html

Hello im writing some PHP and HTML, every time i refresh my page it creates a directory, i only want it to create a directory when someone clicks the submit button, i'm creating a simple URL shorter my code is below

```
<?php
$length = 10;
$mix = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);
$dirPath = "$mix";
$url = $_POST['url'];
$result = mkdir($dirPath, 0755);
$currentURL = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
if (isset($_POST['Shorten'])) {
    $shortened = "<label>http://$currentURL/$dirPath</label>";
    $file = $dirPath.'/index.php';
    $current .= "<?php header('Location: $url'); ?>";
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
}
?>
```

Comment: On a refresh, the data that you submitted is being resent. After the directory is created do a header redirect back to this page.

Answer (score 2):

Name your submit button, including [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

then use a [conditional statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) around the code to execute

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// code to execute

}
```

---

In your case that would be:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$length = 10;
$mix = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);
$dirPath = "$mix";
$url = $_POST['url'];
$result = mkdir($dirPath, 0755);
$currentURL = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
if (isset($_POST['Shorten'])) {
    $shortened = "<label>http://$currentURL/$dirPath</label>";
    $file = $dirPath.'/index.php';
    $current .= "<?php header('Location: $url'); ?>";
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
    }

} // brace for if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

---

Plus, John made a good point about if `$_POST['url']` were to be empty and your script will continue anyway.

Therefore, you could use:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['url'])){...}
```

Comment: Just realized their issue is the POST data being resubmitted on refresh.

Comment: @JohnConde Those refreshes can put a damper on someone's day.

Comment: Until you figure out how to work around them. ;)

Comment: @JohnConde When one uses [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), one is all set ;)

Comment: @JohnConde I picked up on what you said about `$_POST['url']` if it were to be empty. Made an edit.

Comment: Nice. Taking it all the way to completion as always. ;)

Comment: @JohnConde You know me all too well. Kudos to you ;)